# UIPickerView does not react on voiceover within UITableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, accessibility, uipickerview, voiceover

I have an UItableView with multiple UIPickerViews embedded. One of the UIPickerViews does not respond properly when selecting and VoiceOver is enabled. The other UIPickerViews and DateViews do respond properly. VoiceOver will tell the number of components, gives the right selection back when swiping up and down etc. The UIPickerView which does not respond gives a selection rectangle around the UIPicker area, but when tapping only the 'tapping sound' is heard, nothing else.

One other difference is that with the UIPickerViews which do respond correctly, the bounding box of the selection is bigger and even overlaps partially other elements in the UITableView.
I did compare the settings of all checkboxes in the storyboard and tried to disable/enable the checkbox for 'User Interaction Enabled' on the TableViewCell, the ContentView etc but to no avail. 
All settings appear to be the same for all UIPickerViews and for the TableViewCells.

Without VoiceOver all UIPickerViews behave the same.
Any suggestions where to look for and how to debug further?

Answer (score 0):

If you have "isAccessibilityElement" set on a parent container of the element, the container element will block accessibility focus from going into the child element.  You cannot nest AccessibilityElements!  Check that this is not the case!